# Angular material 2 - mat-paginator [length] issue

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use the **mat-paginator** for a table where I want to show data retrieved via an HTTP call, but the problem I have is that I cannot set the **length** of the paginator to the total number of the results I get from the API. In this example, the length is hardcoded in the component, but it shoudn't be a problem (I tried also to set it on the view as [length]="100" and it doesn't work). Here is the HTML:

```
<mat-table #table1="matSort" [dataSource]="dataSource1" matSort>

   <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
            <mat-checkbox name="all" class="" [checked]="isAllChecked()" (change)="checkAll($event)" *ngIf="bulkView"></mat-checkbox>
        </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
            <mat-checkbox class="" [checked]="isAllRowsSelected" [(ngModel)]="element.state" *ngIf="bulkView"></mat-checkbox>
        </mat-cell>
   </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="CompanyAgent"> First name </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <img class="personal-data-table__img" src="/assets/app/media/img/users/100_3.jpg" alt="user" width="50" />
                {{element.firstName}} 
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="CompanyEmail"> Last name </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.lastName}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="city">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="Website"> City </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.city}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
            <span class="btn m-btn m-btn--hover-accent m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill"> 
                <i class="la la-ellipsis-h"></i> 
            </span>
            <span class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-accent m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" (click)="editPersonalDataItem(element.RecordID)">
                <i class="la la-edit"></i>                      
            </span>
            <span class="btn m-btn m-btn--hover-accent m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill"> 
                <i class="la la-trash"></i> 
            </span>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>

<mat-paginator #paginator1
    [length]="pag1.pageLength"
    [pageSize]="pag1.pageSize"
    [pageSizeOptions]="pag1.pageSizeOptions"
    [pageIndex]="pag1.pageIndex"
    (page)="onPaginateChange1($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```

and the component:

```
pag1 = {
    pageSize: 10,
    pageSizeOptions: [5, 10, 20],
    pageIndex: 0,
    pageLength: 100
  };

@ViewChild('paginator1') paginator1: MatPaginator;

this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
    this.personalData = data.users.data.persons;
    this.dataSource1 = new MatTableDataSource(this.personalData);
    this.dataSource1.paginator = this.paginator1;
    console.log('this.paginator1: ', this.paginator1);
});
```

When I console.log this.paginator1, I can see the _length set to 100, but when I open the object, I see the value which is displayed in the browser (10).

[image]

The data is displaying fine in the browser, the only problem I have is that the paginator always shows 1-10 of 10 and I want it to show 1-10 of x, where x is the value I get from the API for the total number of items. 
Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883066/angular-material-2-mat-paginator-length-issue#comment82734180_47883170) by @user4676340 is the right answer to this question:

> Oooooooooooooh I didn't get that you had a pagination in the back-end, not the front-end ! Sorry, my bad. In this case, your first guess was right, except for one thing : you should not bind your paginator to your table. Because in your case, the paginator has nothing to do with your table, it only handles the data. My guess is that this binding to the table is the issue here

(I don't have privilege to convert that comment to an answer so this is what it is)

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I don't think this is mentioned in the doc at all and I've spent a 20/30 mn on that... Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me

```
<mat-paginator  [length]="length" (page)="getServerData($event)" #paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20, 50]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

Add line

```
this.length = count;
```

and remove line

```
this.dataSource1.paginator = this.paginator1;
```

Comment: this.length = templates.meta.totalTemplates; could you please explain it. what is templates here ?

Comment: Removing the line to set the paginator worked for me when doing server paging and setting the length, otherwise if not that statement has to be there. Weird.

Answer (score 4):

Answer found here https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10526

Just remove `this.tableDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;` and definition of paginator from ts.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to take a look at [the internationalization of the paginator](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview#internationalization). I will save you the research time, here is how you do it :

```js
import { MatPaginatorIntl } from '@angular/material';
export class MatPaginatorI18n extends MatPaginatorIntl {
  itemsPerPageLabel = 'Lines per page';
  nextPageLabel = 'Next page';
  previousPageLabel = 'Previous page';
  getRangeLabel = (page: number, pageSize: number, totalResults: number) => {
    if (!totalResults) { return 'No result'; }
    totalResults = Math.max(totalResults, 0);
    const startIndex = page * pageSize;
    // If the start index exceeds the list length, do not try and fix the end index to the end.
    const endIndex =
      startIndex < totalResults ?
        Math.min(startIndex + pageSize, totalResults) :
        startIndex + pageSize; return `${startIndex + 1} - ${endIndex} sur ${totalResults}`
      ;
  }
}
```

In your module, remember to import you custom provider :

```
providers: [
  { provide: MatPaginatorIntl, useClass: MatPaginatorI18n }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This changes the total number in the view, but the problem is that the right arrow button is still inactive so I cannot click on it to get the next set of 10 items from the backend. Can you please advise how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: You should remove all of the inputs of your paginator. In my code, a fully working paginator looks like this : `<mat-paginator #paginator [pageSize]="20" [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 50, 100]"></mat-paginator>`. As you can see, you don't need all of your inputs !

Comment: It doesn't work... I tried it like this: `<mat-paginator #paginator1></mat-paginator>` and also like this: `<mat-paginator #paginator1      [pageSize]="pag1.pageSize" [pageSizeOptions]="pag1.pageSizeOptions"></mat-paginator>`

Comment: The right arrow is inactive. It shows `"Lines per page: 10"`   `1 - 10 sur 120`  and the arrow button is inactive. I am getting only 10 results from the API, so probably that's why the arrow is disabled. If I switch to 5 items per page, then I can go to the second page. The idea is to have the right arrow active so the user can click on it and then the app will request the next set of 10 results from the API.

Comment: Oooooooooooooh I didn't get that you had a pagination in the back-end, not the front-end ! Sorry, my bad. In this case, your first guess was right, except for one thing : you should not bind your paginator to your table. Because in your case, the paginator has nothing to do with your table, it only handles the data. My guess is that this binding to the table is the issue here.

Comment: If I unbind the table and the paginator, when I choose to see 5 results, the table is no longer updated, but I will update it from the component. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's what I was going to tell you : use a `slice` on your array to display only the results you want, with using the values in your `pag1` object !

Comment: so there is no way to use the paginator object and its methods when doing pagintation on the backend? we have to update the UI manually then?

Comment: Again, [the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api#MatPaginator) is there for you. It gives you all inputs of the components, proving that you can use the back-end as the pagination engine.

Comment: @decebal i followed the proposed solution here, but I am still unable to get the arrow working. How were you able to solve this?

Comment: @AkhileshAggarwal - I don't remember exactly how I fixed this because I changed the code many times since I posted this question. I created many paginators since then, so maybe I can help you. Can you please create a plunker or something similar so I can see your code?

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please proceed on the question itself ? It has nothing to do with my answer, and I would like not to be notified for things I'm not contributing to. Thank you in advance !